# Passing structure to signal in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I want to send a structure with a signal in Qt. How can I do this? I know how to send integers, strings, Images etc with a signal but getting confused with the structure part. I read some posts and found out about Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() but I am not understanding how to use it.

```
typedef struct
{
    int EmpId;
    QString Name; 
} StandardData; 

class Data::public QObject
{
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData);

    signals:
        void SignalData(const StandardData &f_objStandardCan);
}
```

The errors I get re
1.explicit specialization in non namespace scope class.
2.Specialization of template must appear at namespace scope
3. struct QMetaTypeId redeclared with a different access.
Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: The code you posted cannot compile. The structure has an identifier with a space in it. Please post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Im working in Linux and posting this from windows machine. So that mistake...I will edit it...

Comment: Try http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-25868.html

Comment: Don't forget `qRegisterMetaType<>()`

Comment: Is your plan to use `Qt::QueuedConnection`?

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need any of this unless you're using queued connections. [Read this](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_custom_data_types_with_Qt#Signals_and_slots) for more info.

Comment: @thuga...No as of now its default connection. I think so it will take Direct Connection in that case.

Comment: @Sid411 If the signal is emitted from the same thread as the object's slot lives in, it will be a direct connection. In that case you don't have to declare a custom metatype using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The errors are because the use of Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is inside your class declaration.  It must be outside any classes or namespaces.  You just need to move it like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int EmpId;
  QString Name; 
} StandardData;

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData);
```

Comment: you dont need the `;` after `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData)`

Comment: Just didn't see the ; and call in class. But nevertheless isn't this a implicit specialication on typedef?

Answer (score 4):

As you have already found out, you must use [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) to make the type known to Qt.

```
struct StandardData {
    int EmpId;
    QString Name;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData)
```

Additionally, you might need to call [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1). Specifically, the function have to be called before using the struct in a queued signal/slot connection or before using it with the [QObject::property()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) API.

```
qRegisterMetaType<StandardData>();
```

## Working Example

#### standarddata.h

```
struct StandardData {
    int EmpId;
    QString Name;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData)
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Register types on startup
    qRegisterMetaType<StandardData>();

    // Continue with the program
    // ...
}
```

## Trick with Static Initialization

There is a trick that can be used to call [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) without modifying any non-related file (like `main.cpp`). This trick uses static initialization. However, I did not find any documentation of Qt that state that this is supported. Additionally, this might cause trouble when using in dynamic libraries.

#### standarddata.h

```
// The header file looks the same as above
struct StandardData {
    int EmpId;
    QString Name;
}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StandardData)
```

#### standarddata.cpp

```
// We don't need this global variable at all. We just want to ensure that
// qRegisterMetaType is called when the application starts.
static const int typeId = qRegisterMetaType<StandardData>();
```

## Q_GADGET

Alternatively, you can use [`Q_GADGET`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_GADGET) instead of [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE):

```
class StandardData {
    Q_GADGET
public:
    int EmpId;
    QString Name;
};

// You still have to call qRegisterMetaType if used for queued signals or
// as property.
qRegisterMetaType<StandardData>();
```

Comment: I have a struct which was being sent over signals & slots. The signal gets emitted but the slot is never fired (strangely, I went through the code and where the `QObject::activate()` is called, the `**argv` was `0x0`. I added the  `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` after my `struct` declaration and `qRegisterMetaType` in the class where I have the signal emitting from / slot retrieving and it appears to work well, thanks for posting!