# Qt Signal/Slots sending a complete structure

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

I am attempting to send a structure via signals/slots between two threads, my signals/slots are connected properly and I have been able to send QStrings containing parts of my data but now I need to send the whole thing and Structures seem most sensible. However when I try the signal is not sent/recieved. The problem seems to be only with sending/receiving the structure, the processing before and after I have tried many ways.

I cannot use pointers such [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397567/using-structure-s-signal-in-qt) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567838/signal-emitting-a-structure) as my data is generated too fast and memory gets over written or freed (I have tried with pointers and assume references will be similarly effected).

I have already added the [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) to my structure. My structure is only a small test for now (to be enlarged later) and is in its own header file.

```
#ifndef RETURNSTRUCT_H
#define RETURNSTRUCT_H

struct Datastruct
{
    int markeridone;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Datastruct);

#endif //RETURNSTRUCT_H
```

Why might my program be unable to send/receive structures? any help is much appreciated.

I am using windows 7, MinGW 32bit, Qt 5.7.0, Qt Creator 4.0.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your debug-log should warn you about it - you can only send types known to the meta-system of qt. Using Q_REGISTER_METATYPE you end up registering types associated with the namespace where the definition was made.

Fortunately you can tell Qt about your struct like this:

```
// after QApplication was instantiated
qRegisterMetaType<Datastruct>("Datastruct");
// but before any class is instantiated that connects signals with this type
```

And it will not try to infer a namespace by looking at the code. Make sure to re-run qmake (or better yet do a clean), or it might be overlooked when building with QtCreator.

If you later happen to pass template-classes of your types via signals, make sure to register them as well, because even if Qt knows about QList, it doesnt know about QList of your type:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QList<Datastruct>>("QList<Datastruct>");
```

On another note: if you #define class aliases, make sure to register them with their real names.

```
#define std::shared_ptr model_ptr
// you can declare your signals like this:
void my_signal(model_ptr<my_model>);
// but have to register the type like this:
qRegisterMetaType<std::shared_ptr<my_model>>("std::shared_ptr<my_model>");
```

Comment: Why oh why would you ever suggest using `#define` here? Even in C it was unnecessary (you had typedef)! In C++, you're supposed to use type aliases: `using model_ptr = std::shared_ptr<model>`. It's also completely fine to use the alias only, not the underlying type name, as long as you consistently use it everywhere.

Comment: I was giving an example out of my head that was similar to a case i had, which was a headache to pin down, **in case you are already using #define** - not _suggesting_ to use #define

Comment: Registering a *template* class may not work as is, you may need to `typedef` or `using` it first, and then register the alias. Also, note that double angular braces at the end of a template type are only allowed **C++11 and above**. Don't make this your habit if you work for other projects, too!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364024/how-to-use-template-types-as-slot-and-signal-parameters-in-multiple-threads and https://steveire.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/implementing-qvariantqmetatype-features-with-template-tricks/

Comment: @markus-nm your answer worked excellently, a little follow up if you have time, is there likely be a speed penalty compared to simply sending a QString (or other more basic data)?

Comment: Is there any documentation that you have to call `qRegisterMetaType` after instantiating `QApplication`? A tested executing the function before entering `main()`. It has worked for me as well. Also note that `qRegisterMetaType<Datastruct>()` can be used instead of `qRegisterMetaType<Datastruct>("Datastruct")`.

Answer (score 4):

In moment, when You declare structure known to QMetaType using macro Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

```
struct Datastruct
{
    int markeridone;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Datastruct)
```

you can send this structure via QVariant. Is nice and simply.
In Your headers declare:

```
signals:
    void sendDatastruct(QVariant data);

public slots:
    void getDatastruct(QVariant data);
```

Using signal in Your code:

```
.....
Datastruct ds;
.....
QVariant data;
data.setValue(ds);
emit sendDatastruct(data);  // now send signal
.....
```

Using slot:

```
void MyObject::getDatastruct(QVariant data)
{
    Datastruct ds = data.value<Datastruct>();
    .....
    // now You can use structure in Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work without some mods as I got a runtime warning:

*startsQObject::connect: No such signal*

I read the doc and found that you must only pass const values by reference:

So you end up with:

```
/* myWorker Class Instance header .h */

struct notifyMsg_t
{
    QString m_TitleSuffix;
    QString m_MessageSuffix;
    int     m_errNumber;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(notifyMsg_t);

signals:
    void sendDatastruct(const QVariant&);

/* MainWindow Class instance Header .h*/
public slots:
    void getDatastruct(const QVariant& data);

/* MainWindow Implementation .cpp */

connect(myWorker,
        SIGNAL(sendDatastruct(const QVariant&)),
        this,
        SLOT(getDatastruct(const QVariant&))
        );


/* Worker implementation .cpp */

void Worker::notify(QString    TitleSuffix,
                    QString    MessageSuffix,
                    int        errNumber)
{
    notifyMsg_t notifyMsg;
    notifyMsg.m_TitleSuffix = TitleSuffix;
    notifyMsg.m_MessageSuffix = MessageSuffix;
    notifyMsg.m_errNumber = errNumber;


    QVariant data;
    data.setValue(notifyMsg);
    emit wrkrError_dbTaskSig(data);
}
```

This code worked.

Note that you don't include a dummy variable in the SIGNAL definition i.e.

/* This     >> */  (const QVariant&)

/* Not this >> */  const QVariant& data

Don't ask me why.

Best regards

Rob

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs a complete working solution (tested on 5.6):

1. Add file StructSignal.h (or whatever)

   struct StructSignal
   {
   QString data;
   bool    checkBox_data;
   ...
   };
   You don't need to add Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SearchResult);
2. In the calling class header file

   public slots:
   ...
   void getResult(StructSignal*);
3. In the calling class cpp file

   connect(&emitClass, SIGNAL(resultParameters(StructSignal*)), this, SLOT(getResult(StructSignal*)));
4. getResult method

   void callingClass::getResult(StructSignal* ss)
   {

   ```
    qDebug () << "getResult";

    qDebug () << "data: " << ss->pattern;
    ...
   ```

   }
5. In the method with the emit:

   StructSignal    ss;
   ss.data = ui->data->text();
   ss.checkBox_data    = ui->checkBox_data->isChecked ();
   ...

   emit searchParameters(&ss);
6. You need to include the signal declaration:

   signals:
   void searchParameters(StructSignal* data);